# Как скрыть элемент на время скролла страницы?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Хочу скрывать блок пока пользователь находится в процессе пролистывания страницы и показывать его через пару секунд после остановки.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    var icons = $('.hot-icons');
    icons.css('display', 'none');
    setTimeout(function(){icons.css('display', 'block')}, 2000);
});
```

В принципе это работает, но не совсем так как надо, потому что при настоящем листании страницы событие scroll происходит много раз. И блок то появляется, то исчезает, в общем, полная неразбериха. Как можно сделать это по-нормальному?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let timer_id,
    w8 = false;

$(window).on('scroll', () => {
    let icons = $('.hot-icons');

    if (w8) {
        clearTimeout(timer_id);
        w8 = false;
    }

    icons.css('display', 'none');

    timer_id = setTimeout(() => {
        icons.css('display', 'block');
    }, 2000);
    w8 = true;
});
```

я бы наверное так сделал, еще можно накрутить логику чтобы само событие скролла срабатывала не каждый раз, а поставить троттл на полсекунды хотяб)